# geoserver-cURL-REST error

Tags: postgis, geoserver, rest

when I try to create a workspace/layer/store following http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/rest-config-examples-curl.html I am getting "System cannot find the file specified".... My curl is working fine with http.

What might be the solution?

Comment: is that error in the response returned by GeoServer or by the shell/command line?

Comment: @iant , its an command line reply

Comment: then curl is broken somehow.

Comment: but I am able do other things successfully, like curl -v http://www.google.com giving a successful result, curl -O iitk.html www.iitk.ac.in giving the html file etc

Comment: did u get the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial thought, have you downloaded and/or made sure you have the rest plugin.  I recall that the standard geoserver donwload comes with one, but this is limited and you need to download the "new" plugin that has more access to the api?

Comment: I have installed Geoserver-2.1.0, so the rest is inbuilt in it. And I am also able to use http;//localhost:8080/geoserver/rest from the browser, But no idea why its giving error in command tool

Comment: Probably didnt explain the issue well. After installing Geoserver I had some similar problems that my scripts that worked using curl suddenly stopped working, very frustrating then I checked the size of the rest plugin that came with the standard install against the one that you can download from the plugins and they were different (same name different size), I dropped the one that I downloaded from the plugins area into geoserver and everything was back to normal.

Comment: @user3026, can you please tell me where can I find geoserver rest plugin. Because in http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer%20Extensions/2.1.0/ I cannot find any rest plugin

Comment: It looks as though the rest api plugin is available for 2.0.3 but not built for 2.1 yet.  Are you able to use 2.0.3?

Comment: I have rest-2.0.3 but not restconfig-2.0.3 . And I think that is why I cannot see anything in http://localhost:8081/geoserver/rest/  I have geoserver 2.0.3 at 8081 and 2.1.0 at 8080

Comment: @3026, I got the restconfig-2.0.3 plugin and able access http://localhost:8081/geoserver/rest but even now I am getting the same error,"System cannod find the file specified"